# Multiple Java versions on CentOS

Tags: java, linux, centos, java-7

I have installed JAVA 1.7_80 in my centOS machine, but when I check the Java version it shows 1.7_09.

I ran the ./java -version in the installation directory which correctly shows 1.7_80, but the global java -version is 1.7_09.

Please refer the link for image - 
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xft1/v/t1.0-9/11667333_914348581933741_3461411661734554342_n.jpg?oh=e8d3037e2f6492757b0f786bd0ae8f77&oe=56318F12

Does someone know what could be the cause or how to fix this?

Comment: Your `$PATH` or whichever equivalent in centOS is probably pointing to your `1.7_09` java.

Comment: What does `declare -p PATH` output?

Comment: Couple of useful links; http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/JavaRuntimeEnvironment https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Installation_Guide/sect-use_alternatives_to_set_default_JDK.html

Comment: guys i am unable to post images as i am new here so you'll have to follow the link. 

https://scontent-sin1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/11058750_914782081890391_7420265492185886036_n.jpg?oh=f7368774851febbd593b97a783a88cf3&oe=5632C732
 
the /opt/java/ path is from an older version that i have deleted,  i figured that should not be a problem as the new /opt/jdk1.7.0_80/ is added in the path too.
Did i miss uninstalling the java correctly ?
 
Also, JAVA_HOME points correctly to the new java, in case anyone is wondering.  :)

Answer (score 8):

*There's default OpenJDK in CentOS,*

---

**OPTION A**

*You have to install JDK with alternatives.*

```
# cd /opt/jdk1.8.0_101/
# alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java 2
# alternatives --config java
```

THE OUTPUT ==>

```
There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
  1           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.101-3.b13.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin/java
+ 2           /opt/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

*Select the version you want from this list.*

---

**OR : OPTION  B**

`#ls -l /usr/bin/java`

OUTPUT : `. 1 root root 22 සැප්   9 02:09 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java`

then `# ls -l /etc/alternatives/java`

OUTPUT : `. 1 root root 26 සැප්   9 02:09 /etc/alternatives/java -> /opt/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java`

```
#unlink /etc/alternatives/java 
#ln -s <new location> /etc/alternatives/java
```

`(ln -s <original file> <link to file> )`

*But I prefer the option A.*